# How to implement Google Map search by address location in fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am trying to create an app. I want to add search by address on google map in fragment Using the following code-

```
public class Search extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener{

private final String  TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

MainActivity main=null;
PlacesTask placesTask = null ;
DownloadTask downloadTask=null;
LatLng latLng;
GoogleMap mMap;
Marker CurrentMarker,FindMarker;

AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView=null;
Button findbtn = null;
private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

//------------ make your specific key ------------
private static final String API_KEY = "**************************************";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.search, container,false);
    autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editplace);

    autoCompView.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item));
    autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    findbtn  =(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.findbtn);
    findbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String location = autoCompView.getText().toString();
            if(location!=null && !location.equals("")){
                  new GeocoderTask().execute(location); 
            Log.e(TAG, "login button is clicked");


                }

        }
    });



    return view;

   }

private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>>{

    @Override
    protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity());
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            // Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input text
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0],3);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return addresses;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<Address>addresses) {
        if(addresses==null || addresses.size()==0){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++){
        Address address =  (Address)addresses.get(i);
        latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
        String addressText = String.format("%s, %s",
        address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
        address.getCountryName());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Find Location");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
FindMarker=mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);


        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng).zoom(14).build();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        double mLatitude=address.getLatitude();
        double mLongitude=address.getLongitude();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        sb.append("location="+mLatitude+","+mLongitude);
        sb.append("&radius=5000");
        sb.append("&types=" + "liquor_store");
        sb.append("&sensor=true");
        sb.append("&key=********************************");
        Log.d("Map", "<><>api: " + sb.toString());

        //query places with find location
        placesTask.execute(sb.toString());

        //for direction Route
        LatLng origin = CurrentMarker.getPosition();
       LatLng dest = FindMarker.getPosition();

        String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);


        // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
        downloadTask.execute(url);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

    }       

 }

@Override
public void onResume() {

   super.onResume();


    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                  getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                }

                return true;

            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("IQWINER");


}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public static ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
    ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

        URL url = new URL(sb.toString());

        System.out.println("URL: "+url);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Load the results into a StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        //Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        return resultList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
        return resultList;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    try {

        // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
        JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

        // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
        resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {

            resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        //Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
    }

    return resultList;
}

class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
    private ArrayList<String> resultList;

    public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
  }
}
```

[enter error description here][2]

how to implement search by address location on Google Map in fragment.Please tell me..

[enter error description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaRWF.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in another way.

You can generate an api key along with Google maps & Google places api in your developers console (Click on the circled link and Enable the api)

[image: shown here]

You can call the api like below with your AutoCompleteView onclick listener or any other listener of your wish

```
private int PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;// declare this globally

//Call this on your listener method
Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                                .build(getActivity());
                startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

This will open the Google place search screen and you can get the result like below

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(getActivity(), data);
            mSearchPlace = place;
            mSearchText.setText(String.valueOf(place.getName()));
// You will get Lat,Long values here where you can use it to move your map or reverse geo code it.
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(place.getLatLng().latitude, place.getLatLng().longitude); 
            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12));

        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(getActivity(), data);
        } else if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // The user canceled the operation.
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: enable the Google places api and you can use the same api key.

Comment: i getting error in  "FindMarker=mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);"  how to resolve it

Comment: i enabled all service which i required

Comment: I'm not sure of what error you're getting. Cant help you without knowing what error it is.

Comment: when i debug my source code i getting error in"FindMarker=mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);".please tell me how to resolve it..

Comment: Please click on on "enter error description here" to see the error

Comment: It shows there is a NullPointerException in your onPostExecute method of your asynctask.

Comment: You should debug at the line number where the null pointer is throwing excecption. Post the whole stack trace or else nobody would be able to help you resolve it.

Comment: again I posted log cat..please check it

Comment: The logcat shows that there's a Null object in line no.70 in your Search class, onClick() method.